# Read-only SVN mirror of a Git repository

Tags: svn, git, github, mirror

I want to use Git and Github for the development of a project. But college requisites says that I must use a SVN repo of their own.

I think it should be possible to develop using Git–Github and use the SVN as a mirror of the Git Repo. Nobody will commit directly to the SVN repo, only to the git repo.

My question is, How to I do this?

I know I can use git-svn and have two ways synch. But I don't want to use it, has it make things too complicated and doesn't allow full git features.

EDIT:

It turns out that as GitHub SVN repos are not real SVN Repos it is not possible to use svnsync. So I started the development of a solution:

http://github.com/Nerian/github_subversion_converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [github's SVN support](http://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support) and [github's SVN write support](http://github.com/blog/644-subversion-write-support) might come in handy in whatever you eventually end up doing.

Comment: This is a perfect solution! I will use both a Git repo and a SVN repo. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that you can not use SVNSYNC with GitHub repos. Because they are fake SVN repos, just a bridge. So I started developing a ruby script to deal with it. Check EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use git-svn to push updates from your personal git repository to the svn repo once in a while?  All you have to do is make it look like svn's being used, so just make sure the names of the committers come through in the commits.